# Minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ where $f(x;\theta)=\frac{\beta^3}{2}e^{-\beta(x-\theta)}(x-\theta)^2\mathbf1_{x\ge\theta}$

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I have this density function for which I am not able to find a minimal sufficient statistic, as required. It does not belong to the exponential families distribution as the support depend also on the parameter, and with the Lehmann Scheffé approach I am not able to separate the random variable $X$ from the parameter $\theta$.

$$f(x;\theta)=\frac{\beta^3}{2}e^{-\beta(x-\theta)}(x-\theta)^2 \mathbf1_{x\ge\theta}, \quad \beta\text{ known}$$

Comment: Please include your work, whatever you have tried and stick to one question per post.

Comment: Ok, thanks. I posted here the correct question: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2886982/minimal-sufficiency-for-fx-%CE%B8-21%CE%B8-x-i%CE%B8-%E2%89%A4-x-%E2%89%A4-%CE%B81

Comment: I have edited this post to include a single question since you already asked the second question in a separate post.

Comment: Your distribution is a shifted gamma with shape parameter $\alpha = 3$, rate parameter $\beta$, and location parameter $\theta$.  It is my suspicion that no data reduction is possible; that is to say, the minimal sufficient statistic comprises the sample itself.

Comment: @MichaelHardy Since $\beta$ is known, it it supposed to be fixed. So the family is only indexed by $\theta$.

Comment: I will edit my answer further and then un-delete it.