# Minimal sufficient statistic for $\theta$ where $f(x;\theta)$ = $2(1+\theta-x) I_{\theta \le x \le\theta+1}$

Tags: statistics, sufficient-statistics

I am not able to find the minimal sufficient statistic for the following density function:

$$f(x_i;\theta) = 2(1+\theta-x_i)I_{\theta \le x_i \le \theta+1}$$

The function does not belong to the exponential family distribution and so I apply the the Lehmann Scheffé Theorem, from which I get that a minimal sufficient statistic should be:

$$T(\mathbf x) = (\min(x_i), \max(x_i), \prod(1+\theta+x_i))$$

But since a statistic cannot depend on the parameter, it is wrong for sure.

Comment: Do you mean the Factorisation theorem when you say Lehmann-Scheffe?

Comment: No, with the Factorisation theorem we just find a sufficient statistic; here instead I need mininality.

Comment: @Lucas : The Lehmann–Scheffé theorem draws conclusions from completeness, and say the conditional expected value of an unbiased estimator, given a statistic that is both complete and sufficient, is the UMVUE. The theorem does not show minimality of a sufficient statistic.

Comment: I think you need to tell us what you thought the Lehmann–Scheffé theorem says, since otherwise we can't tell what  you did.

Comment: Yes, I know. There is another result by Lehmann-Scheffé (1950) in which they show how to find a minimal sufficient statistic, by using the ratio of two likelihood functions.

Comment: I used the same approach of this example: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2885935/proving-minimal-sufficiency-using-lehmann-scheffe-approach-when-joint-pdf-is-onl

Comment: The first step is to find a sufficient statistic, then look for minimal sufficiency of that statistic. For this problem, I think we only have the trivial sufficient statistics $(X_1,X_2,\ldots,X_n)$ or $(X_{(1)},\ldots,X_{(n)})$ for $\theta$. Either of them could be minimal sufficient. The $T$ you found (using Factorization theorem presumably) is not a statistic in the first place, as you say.

Comment: Actually, it is the sample $(X_1,\ldots,X_n)$ which could be minimal sufficient, not the order statistics.